# Locking header jumper

Tags: pcb, switches, header, jumper

I want to implement a 3-header jumper setup in order to switch a microcontroller between two video modes on a PCB. I don't want to use just a standard switch as it doesn't seem appropriate for a change which will happen rarely if ever, so I wanted to go with a jumper instead such as [this one](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/sullins-connector-solutions/SPC02SYAN/S9001-ND/76375).

However, I was wondering whether there exist any kind of nicer, locking jumpers which would require squeezing tabs or some such in order to remove and replace them.

If not, are there better solutions out there? Or should I stop mincing and just throw a tri-pole switch on there and call it a day?

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need them to be locking? Plain old jumpers already take a decent amount of force to remove. Get a batch and try them if you haven't already.

Comment: I haven't worked with them since my PIC demo boards back in college, and I remember them being... dicey at best. As in I would pick the board up flat for transport and they wouldn't be there when I put it back down.

If I just had a well-worn board then that might explain it.

Comment: Maybe it depends on the specific header pins you use and the specific jumpers.

Comment: If it is rarely, if ever used, why not use solder jumpers? Durable and as cheap as they get.

Comment: A little *too* permanent. DIP switches as proposed by Tony Stewart definitely seem to be the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen poor quality jumpers that almost fall off and also seen poor quality dip switches as well as excellent quality in both.  But these are the two best choices. Gold plating gives best protection from oxidation.

https://www.digikey.com/products/en/switches/dip-switches/194

Comment: Ah I didn't even consider DIP switches, the obvious choice. Thank you!